# Select2 Selected item becomes empty on re-select

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I have select element inside a modal form configured as single selection, I load my data using ajax call. The problem is when I select `item1` then hide the modal, when I show the modal again and select `item1` again the select field text becomes empty.

First selection:

[image]

Second selection:

[image]

I tried logging the value and selected object changed.

First selection logged value:

[image]

Second selection logged value:

[image]

So basically the selected object is changed on the second selection. I tried re-initializing my select2 but still the problem persist. I also checked the response json on my second selection and the content is correct.

my html code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="my-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-title" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <form class="w-100" id="my-form">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-title" >Modal</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="d-flex w-100">
                        <div class="w-50 d-flex flex-column pr-1">
                            <div class="d-flex">
                            <select id="my-select" class="form-control" data-style="select-with-transition">
                                <option></option>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

my javascript code:

```
$('#my-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#my-select').select2({
            placeholder: "select item",
            allowClear: true,
            dropdownParent: $('#my-modal'),
            ajax: {
                url: "/my-url",
                dataType: "json",
                delay: 250,
                data: function(param) {
                    return {
                        search: param.term
                    }
                },
                processResults: function(data) {
                    return {
                        results: data.items
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            escapeMarkup: function(e) {
                return e
            },
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            templateResult: function(repo) {
                if (repo.loading) {
                    return repo.text;
                }
                return `<option value="${repo.id}">${repo.name}</option>`
            },
            templateSelection: function(item) {
                console.log(item);
                return item.name 
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: can you show us your code? where comes the log messages?

Comment: @Sysix I updated my question and added a code snippet. hope that helps!

Comment: [Please don't post your code or other text as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)